# How can I convert a CounterBox into a number?

Tags: front-end, notebooks

There must be a possibility to convert a `CounterBox` into a number.
For example

```
CounterBox["Page", {FileNameTake[bookUrl], "someTag"}]
```

The suggestion

```
book = NotebookOpen[bookUrl];
CurrentValue[NotebookSelection[book], {"CounterValue", "Chapter"}]
```

does not work (if the cell is selected programmatically).

I don't know how to referene a cell with a special tag  with `CurrentValue`, but I presume that wouldn't work either.

I don't know why I have the hint here that this question is "subjective"??

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: "... the hint here ..." -- where is "here"?

Comment: `CurrentValue[SelectedCells[], {"CounterValue", "Section"}]` works fine, yet I don't know if that's the answer. The question is a little bit chaotic.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I will follow the instruction in future posts. The "hint" came up in a yellow window shortly after I typed the title of my question. Sorry, I am rather new in this forum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your basic idea seems to work for me.  I used `Cells` instead of `NotebookSelection`.  I tagged a cell with the tag `"C2"`, so that the cell looked like this:

```
Cell["Stuff", "Text",
 CellChangeTimes->{{3.666429490958235*^9, 3.666429492522786*^9}},
 CellTags->"C2"]
```

Then `CurrentValue` returns a number:

[image]

It even works in another notebook.  Let `nb` be the other notebook object.

```
foo = CurrentValue[
  First@Cells[nb, CellTags -> "C2"], {"CounterValue", "Chapter"}]
(*  2  *)
```

Note book selection works, too.  Below I had selected the "Hi there!" cell.

```
foo = CurrentValue[
  NotebookSelection[nb], {"CounterValue", "Chapter"}]
(*  1  *)
```

Comment: Thank you Michael for your very well documented answer.
Finally i tried this on my raspberry pi with version 10.
And it works! But not on my version 9!! with Windows.

What can be the reason?

A lot of things with CurrentValue do work, but nothing with counters like Section, Page, etc.

What might be the reason? Is there a bug? Or might it be some fancy Option somewhere?

Or the fact that I have also an older version of mathematica installed on my system?
I read somewhere that this might cause some trouble (but I never encountered any).

Comment: Hallo, maybe I shouldn't have marked this as answered. I still need a workaround because CurrentValue[] command doesn't work in version 9. And also i wonder if there is a possibility to get this NUMBER, which is generete by the CounterBox[] command and which is to be seeeen in the output. I tried a lot of things, even CopyToClipboard[%] an similar things. When I try to copy the selected number I always get the underlying CounterBox[] command. Has someone an idea? Don't want to post a question again.

Comment: @Darwin1871 Thanks for letting me know.  Feel free to unaccept, if it doesn't solve your problem.  I can't explore V9 as I have V10.  You may edit the question to clarify your needs.  Maybe someone with V9 will be able to help.  My docs say that `CurrentValue` hasn't been updated since V9, so I'm surprised it doesn't work.  Or maybe the docs are wrong.  Who knows.